# /bin/sh: useradd: not found when running RUN useradd app with Alpine

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Hey guys can you check what is wrong with my Dockerfile? I am getting

```
/bin/sh: useradd: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c useradd app' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:12.13.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN useradd app
COPY addressbook/ .
RUN npm install
RUN chown -R app:app /opt/app
USER app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "pm2" ]
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterBadida. Is there any way to `adduser` without the password? I am getting this:

```
Changing password for app
New password: 
passwd: password for app is unchanged
The command '/bin/sh -c adduser app' returned a non-zero code: 1
dockerizing-nodejs $ The command '/bin/sh -c adduser app' returned a non-zero code: 1

```

Comment: RUN adduser -D -g '' app worked like a charm